# Selenium How do I scrape My data based On certain Condition of drop down

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have following example of html code

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="continent">Choose Continent:</label>
  <select name="continent" id="continent">
    <option value="asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <label for="country">Choose a Country:</label>
  <select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
  </select>
   <label for="city">Choose a Cities:</label>
  <select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="Kabul">Kabul </option>
    <option value="Kandahar">Kandahar   </option>
    <option value="Herat">Herat </option>
    <option value="Bajzë">Bajzë</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Suppose there are 7 continents and around 200 countries and 1000+ cities in drop down.
The drop down value(coutry and cities) changes based on continent provided suppose first continent is Asia and the drop down automatically changes to countires associated with in Asia lets assume  first country in drop won is Afghnistan then I want all set of cities for afghanistan and in second loop Similar Asia had to be in the first drop down but Azerbaijan  is to be in country drop down and I want to get all cities for  Azerbaijan.

Any Hint regarding this I dont know how I shall procced. How I shall loop my for loop?

In my opinion I should get Json output maybe this way

```
[{"Asia":[{"Afghanistan":["kabul","Kandahar","Herat"]},{"Azerbaijan":["Cities of Azerbaijan---- "]}]},{"Europe":[{"Albania":["cities of Albania","--"]}]},
```

reference for [website](https://tms17.nepsetms.com.np/client-registration)  on first page choose `client type = Individual` and on 3rd page we can see

```
province, district, municiplity.
```

I want to grab all these data

Comment: yes that json looks fine. or otherwise if you go for list or excel/csv I think it would be messy. Is there any issue with json ?

Comment: Not with json but I dont know how shall I start looping  based on the continents provided

Comment: I can try it out at my end, Is page url or any similar page url handy with you ?

Comment: ```https://tms17.nepsetms.com.np/client-registration``` On first page choose client type = Individual and headover to 3rd page there is state, district, municiplity I think this will be ok for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to scrape all the drop down (3 in number), based on their outcome, i.e select 1st drop down then there will be different outcome on other 2 drop downs.

**Code :**

```
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://tms17.nepsetms.com.np/client-registration")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
first_option = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[formcontrolname='clientDealerType']")))
select = Select(first_option)
select.select_by_visible_text('Individual')


def scroll_till_end():
    driver.execute_script(
        "var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = "
        "scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")


scroll_till_end()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class$='next-btn']"))).click()

scroll_till_end()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class$='next-btn']"))).click()

######### to scrape all the options from all the drop down.
number_of_province = 7
a = 1
z = 1
final_json = []
for i in range(0, number_of_province):
    time.sleep(2)
    select_province = Select(
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[formcontrolname='province']"))))
    select_province.select_by_value(f'{z}: Object')
    time.sleep(2)
    number_of_district = len(
        driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[formcontrolname='district'] option[value*='Ob']"))
    list_of_district = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[formcontrolname='district'] option[value*='Ob']")
    k = 0
    for j in range(0, number_of_district):
        select_district = Select(
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[formcontrolname='district']"))))
        select_district.select_by_value(f'{a}: Object')
        time.sleep(2)
        district = list_of_district[k].text
        k = k + 1
        a = a + 1
        time.sleep(2)
        municipalities = []

        for municipality in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[formcontrolname='municipality'] option"):
            if not municipality.text == 'Select Municipality':
                municipalities.append(municipality.text)
        province = "Province 1" if i == 0 else \
            "Province 2" if i == 1 else \
                "Province 3" if i == 2 else \
                    "Province 4" if i == 3 else \
                        "Province 5" if i == 4 else \
                            "Province 6" if i == 5 \
                                else "Province 7"

        district_json = {
            province: {district: municipalities}

        }
        final_json.append(district_json)
    z = z + 1

print(final_json)
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(final_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: There's a limit in answer body, that's not a full output, but yeah code does work in my local successfully.

Comment: thanks a lot for providing your time for your answer I will try on my machine and accept ans

Comment: @daneilJames : Sure let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks working fine .....Any idea to convert to json ?

Comment: Nah I am not much into json parsing with python. Do you mind creating a new ticket with exact new issue to convert this to json. I'm sure community will definitely help you

Comment: I will try once If I got answer hope you will approve edited answer by me in your answer

Comment: Sure, I can do that.

Comment: ```https://gist.github.com/nawarazpokhrel/ea3d055db17f6d914e8c97d1b4207e05``` I cannot edit your ans but here is gist I created crediting you thanks for your help

Comment: @daneilJames : updated above, and thnx for mentioning in your git :)